# Integral Equation and inverse laplace

Tags: integral-equations, inverse-laplace

[image]

When we get the equation in (5.81), we get complex expressions while taking the inverse laplace transform after moving to the next step. Is there any way to get rid of this complex expression?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After thinking for a long time, I came to the solution.